# try と except 以外の方法

Tags: python, exception

説明のとおり、「時折数字、時折文字列のみ」のような入力に対して、下記のような処理を書いているのですが、何でも `try and except` に投げるのはよくないと聞きました。

下記のような処理の時 `try and except` に頼らず、変数 `a` の振り分けをするにはいかがしたらよろしいでしょうか。お知恵を拝借できましたら幸いです。

**現状のコード:**

```
a = "基本的に数字が入るが、たまに数字を含まない文字列が入る"
b = 0

try :
    b = int(a)
    # 数字だったときの処理
except :
    # 文字列だったときの処理
    pass
```

Comment: 皆様、詳しく具体的なご回答、大変感謝致します！
どの回答も「最も役に立った回答」であり、どれか一つ選ぶなんてとても忍びないことです。
こういう時はどうしたらよろしいでしょうか；

Answer (score 3):

本家(英語)StackOverflowの [Is there a built-in or more Pythonic way to try to parse a string to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262333/) に様々な回答がついていますが、質問中の用途であれば素直に例外機構の利用をおすすめします。`except`では値変換に失敗したことを表す [`ValueError`例外](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) の明示が好ましいです。

```
try :
    b = int(a)
    # 数字だったときの処理
except ValueError:
    # 文字列だったときの処理
    pass
```

---

> 何でも try and except に投げるのはよくないと聞きました。

プログラム設計の一般論として、むやみに例外機構を用いるのが好ましくないことは合意します。

その一方、他プログラミング言語に比べるとPython例外機構は比較的カジュアルに使われるのも事実です。例えば反復的ループ処理を停止させるために [`StopIteration`例外](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) が使われます。

外部記事「[Pythonで例外を投げるときのベストプラクティス](https://qiita.com/hasoya/items/05d4e49d492869875cca)」も参考にどうぞ。

Answer (score 2):

質問から察するに変数aが文字列かどうかを判定したいというのが目的に感じました。
この場合、「isinstance」で文字列か整数かどうかを調べることができます。
例えば、こんな感じでどうでしょうか。

```
if isinstance(a, str):
  # 文字列のときの処理
elif isinstance(a, int):
  # 整数のときの処理
  b = a
else:
  # その他の型のときの処理
  print("不正な値です。")
```

Answer (score 2):

`a`が文字列で、前に符号(+-)がつかない、かつ前後に空白が入らないなら、[isdecimal](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal)あたりはどうでしょうか。

```py
a = "基本的に数字が入るが、たまに数字を含まない文字列が入る"
b = 0

if a.isdecimal():
    b = int(a)
    # 数字だったときの処理
else:
    # 文字列だったときの処理
    pass
```

[int](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#int)は意外と幅広い引数を受け付けるので、上記でダメなら`try`でもいいような気はします。